# sinopia -- how to configuring proxy settings for npmps

Tags: node.js, npm, sinopia

I recently downloaded sinopia server in order to cache packages locally, to save internet bandwidth.  But it is not working as expected, as I am working behind a corporate proxy.  In my setup, I have installed sinopia on my own local mac pc, and I am able to access the url (http://localhost:L4873/) in a browser.

Since, I work behind a proxy, i have properly configured 
 - npm config set http-proxy
 - npm config set https-proxy
I verified the settings and it works without sinopia intervening.

But, when sinopa server is running, if I run npm install , there is no request landing on sinopia, as I finally get error 502.

If I remove the npm proxy settings, and then run npm install , then this time there is a hit to sinopia server, but now the sinopia server fails with connection refused error to a public url.

Is there a way to specify proxy settings for sinopia, without specifying npm config proxy ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Verdaccio is a sinopia's fork and we have documented how to do it.

http://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/configuration.html#proxy

Configuration is almost the same, so, it might be useful for you.